# Sequelize throwing 'id must be unique' on create

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

new to Sequelize library. From my understanding, 'id' is created automatically by sequelize (and thats what I see in the database). However when I go to 'create' an object it will throw this error:

```
    { [SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error]
  name: 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
  message: 'Validation error',
  errors: 
   [ { message: 'id must be unique',
       type: 'unique violation',
       path: 'id',
       value: '1' } ],
  fields: { id: '1' } }
```

The offending code:

```
  db.Account.create({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    allowEmail: req.body.allowEmail,
    provider: 'local',
    role: 'user'
  })
```

Notice ID is not specified anywhere, neither is it specified in my model definition. Also the query it generates runs fine if I run it in postgres admin:

```
INSERT INTO "Accounts" ("id","email","role","verifyCode","provider","cheaterScore","isBanned","allowEmail","updatedAt","createdAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,'cat69232@gmail.com','user','','local',0,false,false,'2016-01-27 04:31:54.350 +00:00','2016-01-27 04:31:54.350 +00:00') RETURNING *;
```

Any ideas to what I could be missing here?

edit:

postgres version: 9.5
stack trace starts here: 
/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:326

Comment: id: {type:DataTypes.INTEGER,primaryKey: true,autoIncrement: true}, Do you have something like above in your model definition.

Comment: I didn't at first, but I tried adding it too just in case. Either way same result, (and it creates the tables too). I also have sync({force: true}) on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Postgres has a habit of not resetting the next number in the sequence (autoincrement field) after bulk inserts. So if you're doing any pre-filling of the data in an init routine or from a SQL dump file, that's probably your issue.

Check out this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65662/postgres-how-to-insert-row-with-autoincrement-id

Comment: I have the same problem - doing a bulk insert (auto-setting up a test DB with pre-filling of data) and upon the first try of `SomeModel.create()` I get his error. Any next try works fine. So, I guess it's the Postgres problem you mention. I checked out the post you linked to, but from what I got as information there - I could not fix my problem. The ID columns in my models are `BIGSERIAL`, so I don't see where the problem comes from. Any ideas?